# Turning an np array into a jagged np array based on boolean conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, boolean

Say I have an array `x` equal to `np.array(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1000 0 0 0 0 1000 1000 1000)`

and I want to turn it into a matrix `array([array([0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]), array([1000]), array([0 0 0 0]), array([1000 1000 1000])])`. How would I do that?

The boolean conditions would be, if it's a string of`0`'s, segment it so that it's one array inside the matrix. If it's a string of `1000`'s segment it the same way.

Comment: Do you mean a jagged array? If so what are the rules you want to implement? Because I've got a pretty easy and completely stupid way of doing what you want but I'm assuming that you have some sort of rules in mind?

Comment: Check out my edit.

Comment: What exactly is the intended output - jagged array of arrays/jagged array of lists/ *jagged* list of arrays/ *jagged* list of lists?

Comment: The intended output is actually a jagged np array of np arrays. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: There's no such thing as a `jagged np array`.  An array may contain objects with differing lengths, including lists or arrays.

Comment: @Divakar seems to have my solution. I'm not sure what to call it if it's not a `jagged np array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach with [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) -

```
m = x!=0
out = np.split(x,np.flatnonzero(m[1:] != m[:-1])+1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [53]: x = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 1000])

In [54]: m = x!=0

In [55]: np.split(x,np.flatnonzero(m[1:] != m[:-1])+1)
Out[55]: 
[array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([1000]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([1000, 1000, 1000])]
```

---

To have an array of arrays as output, wrap it with `np.array()` -

```
In [56]: np.array(np.split(x,np.flatnonzero(m[1:] != m[:-1])+1))
Out[56]: 
array([array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([1000]), array([0, 0, 0, 0]),
       array([1000, 1000, 1000])], dtype=object)
```

---

For a list of lists as output, here's one way -

```
m = x!=0
idx = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(m[1:] != m[:-1])+1, x.size]
out = [x.tolist()[idx[i]:idx[i+1]] for i in range(len(idx)-1)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [94]: m = x!=0

In [95]: idx = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(m[1:] != m[:-1])+1, x.size]

In [96]: [x.tolist()[idx[i]:idx[i+1]] for i in range(len(idx)-1)]
Out[96]: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1000], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1000, 1000, 1000]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in python:

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 1000]
out = []
flag = 0
tmp = []
for i in a:
    if not flag and i==0:
        tmp.append(i)
    elif not flag and i==1000:
        out.append(tmp)
        tmp=[i]
        flag=1
    elif flag and i==1000:
        tmp.append(i)
    else:
        out.append(tmp)
        tmp=[i]
        flag=0
out.append(tmp)
print out
```

Comment: How would I do this with `a`, `out`, and `tmp` being NumPy arrays?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to use numpy. However, accoriding to the original question, the accepted answer should be mine.